# String vector to uint8_t C++

Tags: c++, string, bit

I have a vector **with strings** that represent bits as follows:

```
string str1[] = { "0b01100101", "0b01100101", "0b01011101", "0b11001111"}
```

and I need the exact values added to a uint8_t bits vector:

```
uint8_t str2[] = { 0b01100101, 0b01100101, 0b01011101, 0b11001111}
```

The end result should look exactly like above. 
If anyone has any idea how I could do that I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard function to parse binary strings with "0b" prefix, unfortunately.

You can employ good old [`std::strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) (1 line to call `std::strtoul` and 5 lines of error checking):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

uint8_t binary_string_to_uint8(std::string const& s) {
    if(s.size() != 10 || '0' != s[0] || 'b' != s[1])
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid bit string format: " + s);
    char* end = 0;
    auto n = std::strtoul(s.c_str() + 2, &end, 2);
    if(end != s.c_str() + s.size())
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid bit string format: " + s);
    return n;
}

int main() {
    std::string str1[] = { "0b01100001", "0b01100101", "0b01011101", "0b11001111"};
    uint8_t str2[sizeof str1 / sizeof *str1];
    std::transform(std::begin(str1), std::end(str1), std::begin(str2), binary_string_to_uint8);
}
```

Comment: I edited str1 and str2. Can you please edit them also so it's really clear for the people who might use this later on? Thanks.

Comment: @CsgoTalksCom Done.

Comment: I'm getting some "not a member of" errors. Am I missing any library?Already have these:
iostream, algorithm, fstream, iomanip, sstream, string, cmath, algorithm, iterator.

Comment: `std::bitset` via `<bitset>`

Comment: added it, still "bitset is not a member of 'std'"

Comment: the above compiles on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/ETUn8A) with gcc, clang, and MSVC using at least `-std=c++11`

Comment: @CsgoTalksCom Made it C++03 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Note that these will likely output nearly the same or the same assembly as an algorithm, so an algorithm like in the other answer is almost always preferred. Nonetheless, here are a few more options using loops:

[`std::stoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) - at least C++11 required. We also do not bounds check here, we assume all strings are `>=` 2 in size.

```
std::string str1[] = {"0b01100101", "0b01100101", "0b01011101", "0b11001111"};
const size_t sz = sizeof str1 / sizeof *str1;
uint8_t str2[sz];
for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
    str2[i] = static_cast<uint8_t>(std::stoul(&str1[i][2], nullptr, 2));
```

Since in reality these are most likely going to be variable sized arrays, you may be better off using the actual `vector` type here.

```
std::vector<std::string> vs;
// add a bunch of stuff to vs
...

std::vector<uint8_t> vi;
vi.reserve(vs.size());
for (const auto &s : vs)
    vi.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(std::stoul(&s[2], nullptr, 2)));
```

Comment: If you are not using C++11, you can use `std::strtoul()` instead, which `std::stoul()` calls anyway. You might also consider using `s.c_str()+2` instead of `&s[2]`.